# What limits the maximum zoom-out in the Shader Editor?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

For a Nodes Shader I'm developing, I've built a very large system of nodes in tinkering over the last few weeks. The system is now large enough that I can't view it in its entirety; the maximum zoom-out in Blender is only enough for me to see portions of the node system at once.

What controls this maximum zoom-out? Is it modifiable?

Comment: what about using group nodes?

Comment: `Node groups` (assuming that's what you meant and `group nodes` isn't something else that I'm not familiar with) definitely help to cut down on the complexity; I've got a number of them present already. I could get more aggressive with them, but while thinking about whether I wanted to do so, the question about zoom-out popped up, so I figured I'd see if anyone knew the answer here

Comment: Could the folks who voted to `Close` the question clarify why? I don't think this is answered elsewhere; it seems Blender-specific; and I think I was clear about the question itself. What reason is there to close it?